# Add more indent of section and subsection in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, indentation

I want to add more indent of section and subsection in table of contents, align with the name of the chapter,

[image]
into this
[image]

This is my code

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, inner=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}% load as last package

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
linefill=\bfseries\TOCLineLeaderFill,
beforeskip=0pt,
entrynumberformat=\chapterprefixintoc,
dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter}

\newcommand*\chapterprefixintoc[1]
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~#1\enskip}


\begin{document}
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CONTENTS}
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{PENDAHULUAN}
    contents...
    \section{Latar Belakang}
    contents...
    \subsection{ABCD}
    contents
    \subsection{EFGH}
    ...
    \section{Rumusan Masalah}
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    blablabla
    \section{Tujuan Penulisan}
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    blablabla..

    \chapter{DASAR TEORI}
    contents...
    \chapter{PEMBAHASAN}
    contents...
    \chapter{PENUTUP}
    contents...
    \chapter*{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
    contents
\end{document}
```

How to do that?

Comment: What should happen at Chapter 10 or 100 or 100000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a fixed value for chapter `numwidth` and section `indent` in ToC:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, inner=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}% load as last package

\newcommand*\chapternumwidthintoc{7em}
\newcommand*\chapterprefixintoc[1]
  {\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~#1\enskip}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  linefill=\bfseries\TOCLineLeaderFill,
  beforeskip=0pt,
  entrynumberformat=\chapterprefixintoc,
  numwidth=\chapternumwidthintoc,
]{tocline}{chapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  indent=\chapternumwidthintoc
]{tocline}{section}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry{tocline}{subsection}

\begin{document}
  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CONTENTS}
  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{PENDAHULUAN}
  contents...
  \section{Latar Belakang}
  contents...
  \subsection{ABCD}
  contents
  \subsection{EFGH}
  ...
  \section{Rumusan Masalah}
  \vspace{0.3cm}
  blablabla
  \section{Tujuan Penulisan}
  \vspace{0.25cm}
  blablabla..

  \chapter{DASAR TEORI}
  contents...
  \chapter{PEMBAHASAN}
  contents
  \chapter{PENUTUP}
  contents
  \chapter*{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
  contents
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

If you still want to use **`dynnumwidth`** for the chapter entry:

**Warning:** The following suggestion uses an internal command that can be changed or removed in the future. So the code can break in the future.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm, inner=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}% load as last package

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
linefill=\bfseries\TOCLineLeaderFill,
beforeskip=0pt,
entrynumberformat=\chapterprefixintoc,
dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter}

\newcommand*\chapterprefixintoc[1]
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~#1\enskip}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntry[%
    indent=\ifundefinedorrelax{scr@dte@chapter@lastmaxnumwidth}
      {1.5em}
      {\scr@dte@chapter@lastmaxnumwidth}%
  ]{tocline}{section}
  \DeclareTOCStyleEntry{tocline}{subsection}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
  \cleardoublepage
  \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CONTENTS}
  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{PENDAHULUAN}
  contents...
  \section{Latar Belakang}
  contents...
  \subsection{ABCD}
  contents
  \subsection{EFGH}
  ...
  \section{Rumusan Masalah}
  \vspace{0.3cm}
  blablabla
  \section{Tujuan Penulisan}
  \vspace{0.25cm}
  blablabla..

  \chapter{DASAR TEORI}
  contents...
  \chapter{PEMBAHASAN}
  contents
  \chapter{PENUTUP}
  contents
  \chapter*{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
  contents
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get

[image]

Example with a greater chapter number:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The following uses [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) for achieving the desired alignment (rather than [`tocbasic`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocbasic)). However, the format has been kept the same and should be clear from the context.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft,lipsum}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}% load as last package

\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{CHAPTER~}
\settowidth{\cftchapnumwidth}{\cftchapfont CHAPTER~XX}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftchapfont \cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\setlength{\cftsecindent}{\cftchapnumwidth}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{\dimexpr\cftsecindent+\cftsecnumwidth}

\begin{document}

\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CONTENTS}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{PENDAHULUAN}\lipsum[1]
\section{Latar Belakang}\lipsum[2]
\subsection{ABCD}\lipsum[3]
\subsection{EFGH}\lipsum[4]
\section{Rumusan Masalah}\lipsum[5]
\section{Tujuan Penulisan}\lipsum[6]

\chapter{DASAR TEORI}\lipsum[7]
\chapter{PEMBAHASAN}\lipsum[8]
\chapter{PENUTUP}\lipsum[9]
\chapter*{BIBLIOGRAPHY}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHY}\lipsum[10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's usually a good idea to load `tocloft` with the `titles` option.